# how to get HINDI ISO font for windows7?

Tags: java, fonts, web

I need to develop a hindi news related app .so i need hindi ISO font ,can any one have any HINDI ISO font, please help me to find such a Hindi font

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hindi fonts are already shipped with windows 7 bundle.
however you may use Google IME for the purpose